# Как вывести значение активных чекбоксов?

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть таблица актеров, фильмов и общая таблица где совмещены ид актеров и фильмов. Мне же надо, каким то образом получить актеров, которые снимаются в фильме и вывести их в виде активных чекбоксов.

Проблема состоит в том что я не совсем представляю, как мне передать актеров которые снимаются сейчас и поставить этому актеру активный чекбокс, еще до изменения состояния чекбоксов(при переходе на страницу, чтобы сразу стоял активный чекбокс над нужным актером), сейчас это выглядит просто.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос на само изменение есть, он работает.
Запрос на изменение я сделал так:

```
    $sqlActors = "SELECT * FROM film_actors WHERE  film_actors.`id_film`=" . $id;
    $rowsActors = $dataBase->getALL($sqlActors);

 $sglA = "DELETE FROM `film_actors` WHERE `film_actors`.`id_film` =" . $id;
                $item = $dataBase->executeRun($sglA);
```

И пробегаюсь по всем чекбоксам у которых изменено состояние и добавляю их в базу:

```
foreach ($actors as $actor) {
         $sglA = "INSERT INTO `film_actors` (`id_FilmActors`, `id_film`, `id_actor`) VALUES (NULL, '$id', '$actor');";
         $item = $dataBase->executeRun($sglA);
}
```

Сами же актеры в HTML выводяться так:

```
            echo '<div class="actors-wrap">';
         foreach ($adminActors as $actor) {
            echo '<div class="genre-name">';
                echo '<input class="option-input checkbox" type="checkbox" name="actor[]" value="'.$actor['id_actors'].'">';
                echo '<span class="text"> '.$actor['firstName'].'</span>.';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
```

Мне бы алгоритм как сделать, ну если понятно обьяснил то можно и примером.

Comment: Откуда вдруг появилась переменная `$adminActors`? Это список всех актеров, относящихся не только к актерам текущего фильма? Вам требуется только "алгоритм" как в `html` проставить галки?

Comment: у вас же есть таблица "ид актеров и фильмов" от туда по id фильма берём актёров и ставим им checked, делается такой запрос через inner join